# Возможно ли подключение библиотеки внутри исполняемого скрипта

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

При верстке сайта у меня возник вопрос следующего характера, возможно ли подключить библиотеку внутри исполняемого файла,  я использую стандартный вариант подключения:сначала подключаем скрипт библиотеки, а потом скрипт обращающийся к ней?

Comment: Добавьте конкретики. Вопрос какой-то расплывчатый.

Comment: Значит, пускай к примеру у меня имеется какая-нибудь галерея на jquery, я понятное дело сперва подключаю саму библиотеку jqyery, после - галерею.Потом, к примеру, я инициализирую галерею в отдельном скрипте и тоже его подключаю.Хочу узнать, возможно ли подключить  галерею извне именно в скрипт где происходит инициализация именно этой галереи?Надеюсь я все же сумел хоть немного правильно сформулировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подключен jQuery, то

```
$.getScript(scriptSrc, function(){
  // code here
});
```

Mootools:

```
Assets.javascript(src, {onLoad: function(){
  // code here
}});
```

Comment: Lucky, Весьма признателен и благодарен за помощь